# seg fault on malloc'ing for a string array.  How to get rid of it? I could find it to happen  precisely, when allocating for the second dimension

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

enum { buf = BUFSIZ };

char line[buf], **tab = NULL;

int cur_buf, count_lineMax = -1, count_line = -1,
    k, l;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    cur_buf = buf;

    /*printf("%d\n", cur_buf);*/


    while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) {
            count_lineMax++;
            /*printf("%c", line[j]);*/
    }
    /*printf("%d\n", count_lineMax);*/

    rewind(file1);

    tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
    memset(tab, 0, count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));

    /*printf("%d %ld %ld\n", count_lineMax, sizeof(*tab), count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));*/

    if(tab == NULL) {
            printf("Mem_check\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for(k=0;k<=count_lineMax;k++) {
            tab[k] = malloc(cur_buf+1);
            memset(tab[k], 0, cur_buf+1);

            if(tab[k] == NULL) {
                    printf("Mem_check*\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
    }

    printf("%d %ld %ld\n", cur_buf, sizeof(tab), cur_buf * sizeof(*tab));

    while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) {

            count_line++;

            strcpy(tab[count_line], line);
            printf("%s", tab[count_line]);
    }
    for(l=0;l<count_lineMax;l++) {
            free(tab[l]);
    }
    free(tab);
    return 0;
    fclose(file1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Error 1: failure to validate input** (potential segfault)

Change this:

```
file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

To this:

```
if (argc != 2) {
    fputs("Usage: PROGNAME FILE\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

**Error 2: off-by-one index error** (potential segfault)

Then, initialize the variables as follows:

```
count_lineMax = 0; // -1 is incorrect
count_line = 0; // -1 is incorrect
```

Otherwise, your count will be too small.  I don't know where you came up with `-1` but if you have an empty file, it should have 0 lines, right?  (Try feeding it an empty file.  It will crash.)

Then, move `count_line++` to the bottom of the loop:

```
while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) {
        strcpy(tab[count_line], line);
        printf("%s", tab[count_line]);
        count_line++;
}
```

Also, change the loop condition `k<=count_lineMax` to `k < count_lineMax`.

**Error 3: incorrect error-checking logic**

The following line is non-portable, but it works e.g. on GNU systems:

```
if (tab == NULL) {
```

Change it to this, so it doesn't crash when fed an empty file on systems where `malloc(0)` returns `NULL`:

```
if (tab == NULL && count_lineMax) {
```

**Warning 4: poor constant name, #5: arbitrary / bizarre constant value**

Finally, this is bad:

```
enum { buf = BUFSIZ };
```

The problem is that you don't know what `BUFSIZ` is.  It could be anything (at least 512, I think).  512 is not very large.  Just pick a number, e.g.,

```
enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8 };
```

I recommend not using the name `buf` to avoid confusion with local variables.  Using a coding style helps other people read your code.  Better yet, make the variable name more meaningful:

```
enum { MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 1024 * 8 };
// Or if that's too verbose,
enum { MAXLINELEN = 1024 * 8 };
```

**Error #6: Incorrect output**

Note that `sizeof(tab)` gives you the size of the `tab` variable -- which is a pointer, or 8 bytes on my system.  You cannot use `sizeof` to get the number of elements in `tab`.  Instead, `count_lineMax` holds the number you are looking for.

**Suggestion**

It is unnecessary and potentially dangerous to loop through the input twice.  A malicious user could change the contents of the file between when you first read it and when you read it the second time, causing your program to crash.  Instead, I recommend using a dynamically sized array for `tab`: simply insert lines into it, and when you run out of space, increase the size.  One technique is to double the size of `tab` each time it fills up.  This causes the amortized asymptotic running time to stay linear with respect to file size.

Comment: realloc? is that not frustrating as well with respect to the availability of a larger contiguous block?

Comment: that was a big help. I should learn to introduce as many checks as possible. I started out using malloc/realloc but switched to estimating the total memory and malloc'ing up front. My problem isn't solved yet, though.

Comment: @gyan: Don't think too hard about pleasing the allocator unless you actually know how it works.  Using `realloc` is fine.

Comment: @gyan: Also change `k<=count_lineMax` to `k < count_lineMax`.  At this point, the app is Valgrind-clean.  Go use Valgrind and see what it says about your program.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I'd check with Valgrind as well. I made this : k<=count_lineMax to k < count_lineMax change as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little suspect:

```
tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
```

You're dereferencing tab before initializing it.

Comment: changing that did not work. could you please explain?

Comment: @gyan What did you change? You need to a lot more precise to get useful answers here and not get downvoted into oblivion. You could start by editing your question to refelct what you are trying to do and give a minimal and compilable example.

Comment: What did you change it to? ...please explain.

before that line is executed, tab doesn't point to anything you can count on. Typically a seg fault, a segmentation violation is when you have an address pointing to a segment that's not yours. The *tab follows the pointer to that place. Since you haven't set tab to anything *before* that line, it's pointing somewhere bogus, and the runtime is busting you: throwing a seg fault.

Comment: Sorry. It's a mistake. @chris: Here is what  I changed tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab)); to *tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));

Comment: but I do initialize it to NULL as in "char **tab = NULL"

Comment: `sizeof(*tab)` does **NOT** dereference `tab`.  This is an accepted, traditional way of allocating memory, and often considered "best practices" as far as C goes.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp could you please clarify what's not correct?

Comment: @gyan: I'm not pointing out what's *not* correct, I'm pointing out what *is* correct.

Comment: @gyan sizeof does not evaluate arguments ...